# How to assign exact content of a string to a double in c++

Tags: c++

I dont' have much experience with C++, I have the following problem.
With the following code :

```
double d = 0.0000000;
stringstream ss;
ss << std::fixed << std::setprecision( 2 ) << d;
ss >> d;
```

or

```
std::string content = ss.str();
d = atof( content.c_str()  );
```

Either of the two ways while debuging in MS Visual Studio , I see the value of d is `0.0000000` not `0.00` as in the string `content`

How do I get exact content of string assigned to double d?

May be I should ask a broader question :

I am writing a method that returns a double with precision as needed. For example if I have 2.446343434 as value of d and precision is 2, how can I get my method return d as 2.45 ?

After reading the below answers : I came to know that it is not possible to do such thing. So the next question is :

Even if my above code tries to put 2.45 into double, the C++ runtime will append zeros ( how many ? ) to 2.45 and return right? Is there a way to control appending zeros  to the double?

Comment: You cannot do that because the precision of `double` is fixed by the compiler and `double` has floating-point errors. Use string to hold exact content of string.

Comment: I'm not sure floating-point errors have anything to do with it. Just as with real numbers, there is no distinction between 0, 0.00 or 0.0000000 with floating point numbers. (although unlike real numbers, there is a distinction between 0 and -0).

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Why do you care to control the precision the Visual Studio debugger uses to display the value of a `double` type?

Comment: _"I see the value of d is 0.0000000 not 0.00 as in the string content"_ And the difference is ... what, exactly?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit  the difference will hit him hard, when he will try 1.1 for a change... ;) While technically the zero is the same, it looks like he is missing understanding of `double` and numerical values in computer. Insisting on having two decimal digits may be indicating some money amount processing is intended later. So I hope the answers will enlighten the OP enough to figure out the `double` is not good enough for that.

Comment: Currency should never be stored in floating-point values. Ever.

Comment: Unless of course you are writing an updated version of the classic [Monopoly game](http://monopoly.wikia.com/wiki/Community_Chest): "A floating-point representation inaccuracy was in your favor. Collect $200."

Comment: For bank accounts, maybe not. But for large scale economy simulations, I think floating point is okay.

Answer (score 7):

> I see the value of d is 0.0000000 not 0.00 as in the string

But both of those numbers have exactly the same value. So, a number can have the value 0.0000000 if and only if it also has the value 0.00.

> How do I get exact content of string assigned to double d?

You cannot. `double` represents a numeric value. It does *not* represent a character string.

Also, in more general, that is not possible because floating point numbers cannot represent all the numbers that can be represented by a character string. But that is not a problem with 0, which is indeed representable.

> I am writing a method that returns a double with precision as needed. For example if I have 2.446343434 as value of d and precision is 2, how can I get my method return d as 2.45

You cannot get your method to return a double with the value `2.45` unless the format of the `double` can represent `2.45`. The binary64 format specified by IEEE 754 can not represent `2.45`. In such case, the best that you can do, is to return the representable number closest to the number with 2 significant fractional digits, which in the case of IEEE 754 would be 2.45000000000000017763568394003. The program in your question achieves that.

If that's not what you want, then floating point is not appropriate for your use case.

Comment: I am writing a method that returns a double with precision as needed. For example if I have 2.446343434 as value of d and precision is 2, how can I get my method return d as 2.45  ?

Comment: Thanks so even if my above code tries to put 2.45 into double, the C++ runtime will append zeros ( how many ? ) to 2.45 and return right? Is there a way to control appending zeros  to the double?

Comment: @svasa `C++ runtime will append zeros ( how many ? ) to 2.45 and return right`. No. C++ runtime adds nothing to the `double` value that is returned.

Comment: how do zeroes appear in the double , isn't it the execution environment that says ok the type is double, it will have a representation of so and so number of digits ? please let me know , just for purpose of curiosity

Comment: @svasa zeroes appear, if you print zeroes. How many zeroes there are, depends on how you choose to represent the value, when you convert the double into a character string. If you don't convert the double to a character string, then it cannot be seen. If you print the double using a standard function such as `ostream::operator<<`, then that function is responsible for converting the value to a character string. You can control how many digits the iostream shows, using the API it provides.

Answer (score 3):

The human-readable value for `d` that you're seeing in the debugger, "0.0000000", is just a *representation*, and a fairly arbitrary one at that. The actual `double` object does not store this string, nor *anything* with a fixed number of decimal places.

Its actual identity, at the lowest level, is (a) in binary, (b) encoded according to the floating-point specification, and (c) irrelevant for your purposes. The value is *zero*; period.

The debugger has simply chosen to use seven decimal places when converting the number into something you can read with your eyes and brain. When using `printf` or `std::cout` to similarly output the number for reading, you can pick some other format if you like, including a format with two decimal places to match your original string input. That's just different ways of saying the same thing.

**Do not confuse value with representation.**

Also, your insistence on specifically two decimal places makes me suspicious: if you're planning on using `double` to store currency, *just don't*. Floating-point types are not appropriate for that.